# Is there an implementation of Decision Tree algorithm on Hadoop Mapreduce?

Tags: mapreduce, machine-learning, data-mining, hdfs, mahout

I am looking for an implementation of Decision Tree algorithm on Hadoop Mapreduce.
Is there any implementation ready? I saw that Mahout has only decision forests, and is it possible to use Decision Tree with Decision forests? What is the similarity / difference?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most common way of *distributed* decision trees are forests. Because it is trivial to distribute by computing independent trees, while nontrivial to efficiently build a single tree in a distributed way?

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest certainly parallelizes well, as each tree is built on a (hopefully) random,  independent subset of the training data.

However,  Hadoop would already have made the decision of which data (and how much of it) is on each node.  Depending on the source data,  it may not be practical to randomize upfront before distribution to the nodes.  Also,  the number of observations on each node is no longer a parameter of the RF algorithm, it is controlled by Hadoop configuration for how the data is distributed and degree of data redundancy on the nodes.  It would be very easy for a sample bias to creep into each tree (experts) model without special care.

To parallelize a single tree (CART) across multiple hadoop nodes should be possible though,  as the core computations needed for binary recursive partitioning  in CART such as computing means (a sum divided by a count),  error functions (variance,  gini,  etc) should possible to write in map reduce. It would not be trivial,  as the nodes would need to be very chatty for this to work – sending indices that partition the children nodes of the original sample of data then recursing on the children.  I would think this could work for the really huge datasets,  but for ones that can already "fit" into memory of a single workstration,  it would be much slower.

Revolution analytics did recently post that their version or R has implmented decsion trees on a Hadoop cluster.  I have not tried it,  but it would be interesting to see how it performs on various large data sets.

here is the link:[Revolution Analytics Brings Big Data Decision Trees and New Hadoop Support to Predictive Analytics](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/news-events/news-room/2012/revolution-analytics-brings-big-data-decision-trees-and-new-hadoop-support-to-predictive-analytics.php)